# MySQL TestContainers init-script Schema Creation Failing

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, testcontainers

Running into the following issue trying to create a schema in a MySQL Test Containers instance. It seems like the test user doesn't have the appropriate permissions?

Config:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:mysql:5.7.22:///test?TC_INITSCRIPT=component/db/init_mysql.sql
```

```
Caused by: org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils$UncategorizedScriptException: Failed to execute database script from resource [create schema new_schema CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;]
    at org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils.executeDatabaseScript(ScriptUtils.java:375)
    at org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils.executeDatabaseScript(ScriptUtils.java:313)
    at org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver.runInitScriptIfRequired(ContainerDatabaseDriver.java:196)
    at org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver.connect(ContainerDatabaseDriver.java:132)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils$ScriptStatementFailedException: Script execution failed (component/db/init_mysql.sql:1): create schema new_schema CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    at org.testcontainers.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseDelegate.execute(JdbcDatabaseDelegate.java:49)
    at org.testcontainers.delegate.AbstractDatabaseDelegate.execute(AbstractDatabaseDelegate.java:34)
    at org.testcontainers.ext.ScriptUtils.executeDatabaseScript(ScriptUtils.java:362)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'test'@'%' to database 'new_schema'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:782)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:666)
    at org.testcontainers.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseDelegate.execute(JdbcDatabaseDelegate.java:42)
    ... 71 more
```

component/db/init_mysql.sql

```
create schema new_schema CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Seeing similar issue when creating the mysql image outside the JDBC integration:

```
private static final MySQLContainer mysqlContainer = new MySQLContainer<>(DockerImageName.parse("mysql:5.7"))
            .withInitScript("component/db/init_mysql.sql")
            .withUsername("user")
            .withPassword("password")
            .withExposedPorts(3306)
            .withReuse(true);
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this without creating a custom docker image with the schema pre-created?

Any help would be greatly appreciated I feel like I must be missing something here.

Comment: Also raised here https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/682#issuecomment-734625909

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Worked around this by creating a custom MySQL image with the schemas pre created. Would be keen to hear if there is a better way though.

Comment: Hardly a bad way since pre created image makes container startup time shorter.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid way to solve the problem, even in some docs it is described as a good way to cut times when executing integration testing

Answer (score 4):

Try creating MySQL container and use same password for `root` as for `test` user, in this case `whatever`.

```
@Container
private static MySQLContainer database = new MySQLContainer(MYSQL_DOCKER_TEST_VERSION)
            .withUsername("test")
            .withPassword("whatever")
...
```

Add properties dynamically via @DynamicPropertySource.

```
    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void databaseProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", database::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", database::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", database::getPassword);
        registry.add("flyway.user", () -> "root");
        registry.add("flyway.password", database::getPassword);
    }
```

I am not using flyway but I believe it should work.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the test created on testcontainers repository, the workaround is to specify the password for the root user and to use the root user in your test:

```
MySQLContainer<?> db = new MySQLContainer<>(image)
            .withUsername("test")
            .withPassword("test")
            .withEnv("MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD", "test")
            ...
```

Reference: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/commit/2fa00ddbd1f42a20656d5e39d58cdedfbd483dcf#diff-f49cf0d09246a5351504ca32a08deb74e80ac7d61ad012f02d8f09c36508737bR65

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I solved it using the following:

```
    @Container
     public static JdbcDatabaseContainer mariaDB = (JdbcDatabaseContainer) new MariaDBContainer("mariadb:10.5.11-focal")
    .withDatabaseName("dbName")
    .withInitScript("db.migration/init.sql")
    .withUsername("your user")
    .withPassword("your password")
    .withUrlParam("param", "1")
    .withUrlParam("param", "2");
```

Basically, I'm creating the DB via the POJO. A bit hackish but works. But maybe the option of creating the root user with custom password is a better solution.